# Join tables based on geometry and nearest timestamp BigQuery SQl

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables; df1 contains Date1 (timestamp) and PolygonWKT (geometry), df2 contains Date2 (timestamp) and PointWKT (geometry). I joined df1 and df2 based on geomtery, so each PointWKT fell under the corresponding PolygonWKT. The problem is, that Date1 and Date2e columns are messed up and what i also need is  matched Date1 and Date2.
I would like to join tables **based on geometry** and also **closest timestamp match between Date1 and Date2.**

```
 df2
 | PointWKT  |      Date2            |     
 --------------------------------------
 |    b    | 2020-05-05 12:00:00 UTC |
 |    b    | 2020-05-05 12:00:10 UTC |
 |    b    | 2020-05-05 12:00:20 UTC |
 |    b    | 2020-05-05 12:17:00 UTC |
 |    c    | 2020-05-06 18:00:00 UTC |


df1
 | PolygonWKT  |      Date1          |
--------------------------------------
 |    A    | 2020-05-03 9:00:00 UTC  |
 |    A    | 2020-05-03 9:30:10 UTC  |
 |    B    | 2020-05-05 12:05:00 UTC |
 |    B    | 2020-05-05 12:25:00 UTC |
 |    C    | 2020-05-06 18:05:00 UTC |
```

First part of the code is correct but second part doesn't return what i want:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM `xxx.yyy.df1` as df1 ,
    `xxx.yyy.df2` as df2
    WHERE ST_Contains (df1.PolygonWKT, df2.PointWKT) 


    AND ( 
    df2.Date2 BETWEEN df1.Date1 AND TIMESTAMP_ADD(df1.Date1, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)



    
desired df

| PointWKT  |      Date2            || PolygonWKT  |      Date1          |     
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |    b    | 2020-05-05 12:00:00 UTC | |    B    | 2020-05-05 12:05:00 UTC |
 |    b    | 2020-05-05 12:00:10 UTC | |    B    | 2020-05-05 12:05:00 UTC |
 |    b    | 2020-05-05 12:00:20 UTC | |    B    | 2020-05-05 12:05:00 UTC |
 |    b    | 2020-05-05 12:17:00 UTC | |    B    | 2020-05-05 12:25:00 UTC |
 |    c    | 2020-05-06 18:00:00 UTC | |    C    | 2020-05-06 18:05:00 UTC |
```

What would be a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to join tables **based on geometry** and also **closest timestamp match between Date1 and Date2**.

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT  
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(df2.PointWKT, df2.Date2, df1.PolygonWKT, df1.Date1) 
    ORDER BY ABS(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(df2.Date2, df1.Date1, SECOND)) 
    LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM `xxx.yyy.df1` AS df1 ,
  `xxx.yyy.df2` AS df2
WHERE ST_CONTAINS(df1.PolygonWKT, df2.PointWKT) 
GROUP BY TO_JSON_STRING(STRUCT(df2.PointWKT, df2.Date2))
```

If to apply to sample data similar to one in your example -

```
WITH `xxx.yyy.df1` AS (
  SELECT ST_GEOGPOINT(1,2) PolygonWKT, TIMESTAMP '2020-05-03 9:00:00 UTC' Date1 UNION ALL
  SELECT ST_GEOGPOINT(1,2), '2020-05-03 9:30:10 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT ST_GEOGPOINT(1,3), '2020-05-05 12:05:00 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT ST_GEOGPOINT(1,3), '2020-05-05 12:25:00 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT ST_GEOGPOINT(1,4), '2020-05-06 18:05:00 UTC' 
), `xxx.yyy.df2` AS (
  SELECT ST_GEOGPOINT(1,3) PointWKT, TIMESTAMP '2020-05-05 12:00:00 UTC' Date2 UNION ALL
  SELECT ST_GEOGPOINT(1,3), '2020-05-05 12:00:10 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT ST_GEOGPOINT(1,3), '2020-05-05 12:00:20 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT ST_GEOGPOINT(1,3), '2020-05-05 12:17:00 UTC' UNION ALL /* this value adjusted based on exapected result sample - as it looks as a typo */
  SELECT ST_GEOGPOINT(1,4), '2020-05-06 18:00:00 UTC' 
)
```

output is

```
Row PointWKT    Date2                   PolygonWKT  Date1    
1   POINT(1 3)  2020-05-05 12:00:00 UTC POINT(1 3)  2020-05-05 12:05:00 UTC  
2   POINT(1 3)  2020-05-05 12:00:10 UTC POINT(1 3)  2020-05-05 12:05:00 UTC  
3   POINT(1 3)  2020-05-05 12:00:20 UTC POINT(1 3)  2020-05-05 12:05:00 UTC  
4   POINT(1 3)  2020-05-05 12:17:00 UTC POINT(1 3)  2020-05-05 12:25:00 UTC  
5   POINT(1 4)  2020-05-06 18:00:00 UTC POINT(1 4)  2020-05-06 18:05:00 UTC
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I got an error message in the row GROUP BY: Grouping by expressions of type GEOGRAPHY is not allowed at [6:10]. Any suggestions how to deal with it?

Comment: see update with corrected treatment for geography types. original example was with strings - so I missed this part. it is fixed now

Comment: amazing! Works perfectly, thank you so much for this!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data, you are pulling the dates in the wrong order.  Does this do what you want?

```
df2.Date1 BETWEEN df2.Date1 AND TIMESTAMP_ADD(df2.Date1, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
```

Comment: I think the whole concept of this row is wrong for my purpose. I think Mikhail answer could help.